# Trying to solve $\lim_{x\to1}{\frac {\cos(\frac {\pi x} {2})} {1-\sqrt x}}$ without L'Hospital

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to solve the following limit without L'Hopital
$$\lim_{x\to1}{\frac {\cos(\frac {\pi x} {2})} {1-\sqrt x}}$$
But I have no clue how to solve this. Rationalization doesn't get me anywhere with the denominator, and I don't see anything to do with numerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward way is to let $y = 1-x$.  Then 
$$\cos\frac{\pi x}{2} = \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2} (1-y) \right) = \sin \frac{\pi y}{2} 
= \frac{\pi y}{2} + O(y^3)$$
$$ 1-\sqrt{x} = 1 - \sqrt{1-y} = \frac{y}{2} + O(y^2)
$$
So for sufficiently small $y$, the function gets arbitrarily close to 
$$ \frac{\frac{\pi y}{2} }{\frac{y}{2}} = \pi
$$

Comment: Excellent thinking, but how did you see this? What element of the question got you to try this particular substitution?

Comment: This is literally reproducing the proof of L'Hopital's rule in this special case. That is, he basically computed $(1-\sqrt{x})'(1)=-1/2$ and $(\cos(\pi x/2))'(1)=-\pi/2$ to get an answer of $\pi$.

Comment: The $y = 1-x$ is motivated by the fact that the llimit is as $x \rightarrow 1$ but I want to expand in something that goes to zero.  And yes, Ian, this sort of method only will work when repeated applications of l'Hospital's rule will eventually give the answer.  So I guess it really doesn't solve the problem "without l'Hospital" in spirit.

Answer (score 2):

Define $f(x)=\cos \left ( \frac{\pi x}{2} \right ) \left ( 1 + \sqrt{x} \right )$. By rationalization and factoring a minus sign, you have

$$-\frac{f(x)}{x-1}$$

Since $f(1)=0$ this can be rewritten as

$$-\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}$$

So the limit of it as $x \to 1$ is $-f'(1)$, by the definition of the derivative. Calculating $f'(1)$ by a limit process seems somewhat difficult; you would need to replicate the argument for the product rule and the argument for the derivative of $\cos$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}2\right)$ then

$$\lim_{x\to1}{\frac {\cos(\frac {\pi x} {2})} {1-\sqrt x}}=2\lim_{x\to1}{\frac {f(x)-f(1)} {(1-\sqrt x)(1+\sqrt x)}}=-2\lim_{x\to1}\frac {f(x)-f(1)} {x-1}=-2f'(1)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the substitution $y=x-1$, your limit would be then equal to

$$
\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\cos(\tfrac\pi2(y+1))}{1-\sqrt{y+1}},
$$

after using the angle-addition formula and rationalizing the denominator you'll get :

$$
\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\sin(\tfrac\pi2y)(1+\sqrt{y+1})}{y},
$$

which is simpler to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

A brute-force L'Hospital avoider: Substitute $h=1-\sqrt x$, and you get
$$ \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\cos(\frac\pi2  (1-h)^2)}{h} $$
which is the derivative of $\cos(\frac\pi2(1-x)^2)$ at $x=0$. Differentiate symbolically and evaluate.